# fist time SQL syntax. Concatenate some string to each instance of a field in a table

Tags: mysql, concatenation

using mySQL for the first time for what I believe must be a really easy task.

I have a table called "incidents". In that table there is a field called "id". There are about 90 records in this table.

For each record, I'd like to concatenate:

```
'somestring'+id
```

What I've tried:

```
SELECT * FROM incident;
CONCAT('https://somewebsite.com/reports/view/',id);
```

After hitting go I'm then being told I have an error in my syntax?

How would I create a SQL statement that returns the concatenation of the same string with each unique ID in a table where the ID is the field to be appended?

Comment: Yes. SQL syntax is well defined and there is an entire manual written [covering the particular MySQL dialect](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html) .. time to get familiar with the resources. (Since that will likely be too hard to initially grok, try "SQL tutorials" to absorb in the general patterns.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT CONCAT('https://somewebsite.com/reports/view/',id) FROM incident;
```

Comment: You can always add a field alias (and **as**), so that working with the output is easier.